# Changes are not reflected in foreach in SwiftUI

Tags: swiftui

I tried the following view. I expect that when I tap the update button, rectangle's color will change. But nothing happen. Why do this thing happen?

```swift
struct SwiftUIView: View {
    @State var index: Int = 0

    var colors = [Color.red, Color.blue, Color.orange, Color.green]

    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            VStack {
                ForEach(0..<colors.count) { i in
                    if i == self.index {
                        Rectangle()
                            .fill(self.colors[i])
                            .frame(width: 100, height: 100)
                    }
                }
            }
            .navigationBarTitle("title")
            .navigationBarItems(trailing: Button(action: {
                self.index += 1
            }) {
                Text("Update")
            })
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changing the index value does not affect any view, so it does not redraw. Remove the `ForEach` and simply display the `Rectangle` like this:

```
struct SwiftUIView: View {
    @State var index: Int = 0

    var colors = [Color.red, Color.blue, Color.orange, Color.green]

    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            VStack {
                Rectangle()
                    .fill(self.colors[index])
                    .frame(width: 100, height: 100)           
            }
            .navigationBarTitle("title")
            .navigationBarItems(trailing: Button(action: {
                self.index += 1
            }) {
                Text("Update")
            })
         }
    }
}
```

Now when index changes, the `Rectangle` must redraw because it's fill color is directly dependent on the value of index.

Comment: Thank you!  Your solution looks very good!  By the way, I wonder how SwiftUI detect dependencies. Is there document written about this thing?

Comment: You're welcome. Well, there are many documents written about SwiftUI. There are many good sites and tutorials available. I'm pretty new to it myself. If my answer was helpful, please accept it. Good luck to you!

Comment: If by dependencies you mean how it knows to update the color when the index changes in your example, there is nothing fancy going on here: If a @State property changes for a View, before the next frame is rendered, it calls body again to get an updated View. You can see that happening by setting a breakpoint in your body property code.

Comment: Runnable example: https://github.com/ralfebert/SwiftUIPlayground/blob/master/SwiftUIPlayground/Views/ColorCycleView.swift

Comment: Thank you for giving me an example! It helps me a lot!